# Another get property name in C# (this one is static)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I looked and everywhere are many examples how to do property name resolution, but I didn't find that would solve my usage.

My idea of `User` looks like this:

```
class Entity<T> where T : class
{
    public static String GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
    {
        return ((MemberExpression)expr.Body).Member.Name;
    }
}

class User : Entity<User>
{
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoggedOn { get; set; }
}
```

**Question:** How to implement property name resolution if I want to use it like this?

```
Debug.Assert("UserName" == User.GetField(x => x.UserName));
Debug.Assert("LastLoggedOn" == User.GetField(x => x.LastLoggedOn));
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

*Notes: I could do `var u = new User();` and then `u.GetName(() => u.UserName)` but in my case, I don't have an instance of the entity*

**EDIT 1**: Thanks to Darin, I updated my code. I need to get `LastLoggedOn` work too.

Debugging shows, that value of `expr` is `{x => Convert(x.LastLoggedOn)}` (don't know what the Convert means)

```
InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'.
```

**EDIT 2/Answer**:  After some debugging I've composed this "solution". I don't like it, but it seems to work.

```
public static string GetName(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    MemberExpression memberExp = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExp != null)
        return memberExp.Member.Name;

    // for DateTime
    UnaryExpression unaryExp = expression.Body as UnaryExpression;
    if (unaryExp != null)
    {
        memberExp = unaryExp.Operand as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExp != null)
            return memberExp.Member.Name;
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("'expression' should be a member expression or a method call expression.", "expression");
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you actually want to do.  Please elaborate.

Comment: -1 for who down voted this question.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `<T>` from the `GetName` static method and you are good to go (the compiler should have warned you about this by the way):

```
public class Entity<T> where T : class
{
    public static string GetName(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
    {
        return ((MemberExpression)expr.Body).Member.Name;
    }
}

public class User: Entity<User>
{
    public String UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can write:

```
string name = User.GetName(x => x.UserName);
```

Comment: Ok, I removed <T> and it works. Could you have a look at the exception that it throws for DateTime please?

Answer (score 1):

You can call your static method on `Entity<T>`:

```
string name = Entity<User>.GetName<User>(u => u.UserName);
```

You have made both the method and the class generic, both taking a type parameter. You probably only want the class to be generic, because it looks like that is how you are using it.